# Get element by binding for 'ng-src' not working, Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, protractor

In Angular Phone cat application (step-10), I am not able to use `element(by.binding('bindingName'))`   [Protractor locators](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md#locators)

**Tutorial link**: [Angular phone cat app (step-10, test)](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_10/#test)

**Details**:

```js
// Working
expect(element(by.css('img.phone')).getAttribute('src'))
  .toMatch(/img\/phones\/nexus-s.0.jpg/);

// Not Working
expect(element(by.binding('mainImageUrl')).getAttribute('src'))
  .toMatch(/img\/phones\/nexus-s.0.jpg/);
```

```html
<img ng-src="{{mainImageUrl}}" class="phone">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`by.binding` would not work in this case [by definition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.binding).

According to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/a877268f35cb0df8f34f60b71ad7201fef58d189/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L61), it would only match an element if, at least, there is a `ng-binding` class on an element.

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood that protractor can be used for all {{ }} expressions

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to qualify alecxe's answer just a little. Any `{{ }}` expressions work, as long as *it's not part of an attribute*

For example:

```
<p class="phone">{{someText}}</p>
```

can be found via:

```
element(by.binding('someText'))
```

In other words, your template does not need to contain the ng-binding class, as it's generated automatically by Angular. That being said, there is a [bug](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/157) currently where if the binding is part of an attribute or attribute-value, the ng-binding class is not generated by Angular and Protractor will not be able to locate the element.

Answer (score 0):

This is my problem too and I can not find any protractor feature to solve that so this is my suggest solution. :)
This solution bases on protractor can get element by ng-bind and get value attribute of input. (I have no idea why getText() input not work :D)

```
..
  <img ng-src="{{mainImageUrl}}" class="phone">
  <input type="hidden" ng-bind="mainImageUrl" value="{{mainImageUrl}}">
..
```

in javascript:

```
    element(by.binding('mainImageUrl')).getAttribute('value')
       .then(function(text){
          expect(text.toMatch(/img\/phones\/nexus-s.0.jpg/));
       });
```